# Silverlight 5.1.41212.0 and Windows 10 issues

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to port a Silverlight application for windows 10. The application was designed for windows 7. If I compile the project with VS2015 in windows 10 with Silverlight 5.1.41212.0 then it does work. But the project compiles in Release mode but if I build the project in Debug mode then I get the following error:
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ObservableObjectCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Why the project compile for release mode but not for Debug mode. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Open the raw project in an editor and check if there is anything wrong with it. MSBuild verbose logging might also give you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a bit, following 2 steps helped me to solve the problems:

A. Clean the whole project for both Debug & Release,

B. Install Microsoft Silverlight Toolkit from http://silverlight.codeplex.com

After these all these problems gone.